# How to initialize Bootstrap tooltips globally in Angular 13 app

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm working with **Bootstrap v5.0** in **Angular 13**, I tried to implement tooltip using

```
data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Refresh"
```

This is how I want it

[image]

Getting it like this, the title string shows up when the mouse hovers the link

[image]

**angular.json**

```
  "styles": [
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
      "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
      "src/styles.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
   ]
```

**Update :**

If I initialize it in some component, it works for that component. Is there any way I could initialize it globally?

```
  import {} from "....";
  declare var bootstrap: any;
    
  export class YourComponent implements OnInit {  
       
  ngOnInit(){
      // Bootstrap tooltip initialization
      var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
      var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
          return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
      }) 
    }
  }
```

Thanks! will appreciate any help.

Comment: the styles or js files are not loaded. can you put the code where you load bootstrap css and js?

Comment: Thank you for your reply @MahdiZarei, I've added the code please check, other bootstrap components are working fine, problem is with tooltips only.

Comment: did you initialize tooltips in `ts` file before using them?

Comment: [Tooltips are opt-in for performance reasons, so you must initialize them yourself.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/tooltips/#overview)

Comment: Also, you should update your package. Many fixes and improvements have been made since 5.0.

Comment: Yes I initialized it as mentioned in [Bootstrap 5 tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68100968/bootstrap-5-tooltip-not-working-in-angular-11-project), it works for the initialized component's view, is there any way I could initialize it globally?